# How do I use Vuelidate 2 in browser

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, es6-modules, vuelidate

I am from the stone age - the days where we just dropped in a .js file or a CDN reference to one and wrote our code to start using it, but those days seem to be all but gone. I want to use Vuelidate 2 in the browser but have been unable to put the pieces together. I've run

`npm install @vuelidate/core @vuelidate/validators -g`

and that seems to be the extent of the instructions for [installation](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#installation). Now what? Next it gives an example of importing the modules. However, this is es6 syntax that would need to be transpiled (at least traditionally) for wide use in browsers right?

So do I need Browserify, Babel, Webpack ... what do I have to do to just be able to write client-side javascript for my page that uses Vuelidate? I'm not working on a SPA, wanting to run javascript server-side, or particularly concerned with my page size. Right now I just want to try out out Vuelidate 2. I've also run into issues with other libraries not being precompiled to a browser-ready .js file to, I guess, allow you to choose the specific modules you need for optimization. It's becoming increasingly impossible to get by without knowing how to do this, but no easier to figure out where to start.

Comment: This lib is meant to be used in a Vue SPA application ***only***, they call themselves "Simple, lightweight model-based validation **for Vue.js**" ([link](https://vuelidate.js.org/#getting-started)). In short, if you lack the intentions and ability to use Vue.js, then better not waste time and effort even thinking of trying to use this lib... PS I also found this: **https://formvalidation.io/** - don't know it, but seems OK

Comment: Thanks for that reference. I am using Vue.js. I was working all day yesterday trying to get Vuelidate 1 going with the custom validation I need with minor success but then found that Vuelidate 2 seems to address a lot of its shortcomings.

Comment: I've posted how to create an `iife` export of `@vuelidate/core` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636365/1891677) (or any other npm package, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working the "Stone Age" way. I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I wanted to use Vue and Vuelidate on one of the pages. After several attempts and nearly going back to JQuery I did the following:

Downloaded the Scripts. (CDN would have had issues coming into my company's network)

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/vue.global.js"></script>
<!--  Vuelidate -->
<script src="~/Scripts/vue.demi.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/vue.validate.core.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/vue.validators.js"></script>
```

Then on the Page in the script tags I had the following:

```js
const MyApp = {
        data() {
            return {
                v$: Vuelidate.useVuelidate(),
                vv: VuelidateValidators,
                formData: {
                    id: '',
                    name: '',
                    desc: '',
                    blahblah: ''
                }
            }
        },
        validations(){
            return {
                formData: {
                    id: {required: this.vv.required },
                    name: { required: this.vv.required},
                    desc: { required:this.vv.required},
                    blahblah: { required: this.vv.required}
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            
        },
        computed: {
            formIsValid() {
                return !this.v$.formData.$invalid;
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            
        }
    }

const app = Vue.createApp(MyApp).use(Vuelidate).mount('#app');
```

The Form looks something like this:

```html
<form id="MyForm row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': v$.formData.id.$error }">
<label for="id" class="control-label required">ID</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="id" name="ID" placeholder="ID" v-model="formData.id" v-on:blur="v$.formData.name.$touch()">
<small v-if="v$.formData.id.$error" class="help-block">The ID field is required</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': v$.formData.name.$error }">
<label for="name" class="control-label required">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" v-model="formData.name" v-bind:readonly="addMode ? false : true" v-on:blur="v$.formData.name.$touch()" required>
<small v-if="v$.formData.name.$error" class="help-block">The Name field is required</small>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Please use this answer to get a general idea of the approach I took and do not copy and paste and expect it to work as is thank you.